# How to retrieve particular nodes in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a post app with Firebase Realtime Database.

The app needs a bookmark function, but I don't know how to load the bookmarked (selected) post.

Database structure:

[image]

Code:

```
databaseReference = databaseReference.child("post").child(getLen()).child("all-posts").child("-KYbMBatKdoWYw45-2pp").child("bookmarkUsers").orderByChild(myUserId).equalTo(myUserId);
```

but this code is not working. Why doesn't it work? I think that it only returns `bookmarkUsers` child node.

Do I have to make another node only for bookmark?

I already made a node only for bookmark, but I could't manage `bookmardCount` and `starCount` synchronization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseStorage Posts=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");

Posts.child("0").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 for(DataSnapshot DS: dataSnapshot)
                  {
                          //Get all other Values Except bookmarkusers and store them

                                       String   POST_NAME = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                          Posts.child("0").child(POST_NAME)addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotf) {


                                            for(DataSnapshot BOOK: dataSnapshotf)
                                             {
                                             //Collect all BookMarks and store them
                                              }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to make another node only for bookmark?

Yes, you do. To get more information, read about structuring you data in firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).

> I already made a node only for bookmark, but I could't manage bookmardCount and starCount synchronization.

You will need to keep the `bookmarkCount` and `starCount` inside the post node itself.